# Singleton with clean arhirecure

Tags: singleton, clean-architecture

I have a state class (singleton), it is injected into the viewmodel as singleton.

```
data class EngineViewState(
    private val cylinderQuantity: MutableState<Float> = mutableStateOf(0f),
    private val inGapNormal: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("0.0"),...


) {

    fun getCylinderQuantity() = cylinderQuantity
    fun setCylinderQuantity(cylinderQuantity: Float) {
        this.cylinderQuantity.value = cylinderQuantity
    }

    fun getInGapNormal() = inGapNormal
    fun setInGapNormal(inGapNormal: String) {
        this.inGapNormal.value = inGapNormal
    }
    ...
}
```

I interact with it to store the state of the data entered by the user. In the future, this data is needed for calculation, I have a question how to get this data correctly in accordance with clean arhirecure? Is it correct to use the same object as a data source in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to use the same object as a data source in the repository?

Your singleton belongs to the view and like any data from I/O devices like the UI they should be passed as request models to the use cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I understand correctly, do I need one use Case that will provide my Engine ViewState class? Shouldn't I create a usecase for each field of the Engine View State use Case class (example: getCylinderQuantityUseCase)?